# jQuery auto select div on page load

Tags: jquery, html, slide

all. I have jQuery that slides div's horizontally on click on links. Problem is that on page load no link is clicked so no div is visible (only ul is visible). I would like to div with id "page1" be selected on page load. How to do that? I'm not posting any html, its few div's with id's page1 through page9, and ul with links referenced to div id.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a.panel').click(function() { 
        var $page = $($(this).attr('href')), $other = $page.siblings('.active');
        if (!$page.hasClass('active')) { 
            $other.each(function(index, self) { 
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({ left: $this.width() }, 500);
            });
            $page.addClass('active').show().css({ left: -($page.width()) }).animate({ left: 0 }, 500);
        } 
     return false;
   });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you want to show 1st link in the `a.panel` that trigger a `div` to show

just use

```
$(docmuent).ready(function () {
    $('a.panel:nth(0)').click();
});
```

for 1st element use `:nth(0)`

for second `:nth(1)` as index starts from `0`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. Just, don't know why it doesn't put that link in focus state (because I have css that targets focused links) but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you find the first div in the page and display that. You've not shown your HTML so I can't give you the selector, but something like this should work:

```
$('.page:first')
    .addClass('active')
    .show()
    .css({ left: -($page.width()) })
    .animate({ left: 0 }, 500);
```

Comment: Can u tell my how to set focus on link  <a class="panel" href="#page1" >Ključni pokazatelji</a> on page load, maybe that would be a better solution

Comment: I don't see how that's a better solution as you'd then have to trigger a click manually, which isn't best practice.